# meteor reset on a remote database

Tags: mongodb, deployment, meteor

I've a self hosted meteor application and every I need to erase the database, I've to do it by hand. On my local machine I simply run `meteor reset` and the database gets erased. On the deploy machine `meteor reset` takes no effect at all, even with the environment variable `MONGO_URL` set.

Is it possible to use `meteor reset` on a remote database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edit] - misread your question.  From my understanding, "meteor reset" only works against your mongo instance when it controls the instance.  Since you're telling it that you are going to use your own instance (through setting MONGO_URL) it figures you'll manage it.

In that case, use mongo shell to connect to your mongo instance, then switch to the database and drop it.

```
use yourDatabaseName;
db.dropDatabase()
```

Docs are [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/#db.dropDatabase)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the app and redeploy it again:

`meteor deploy -D yoursite.meteor.com`

And deploy again:

`meteor deploy yoursite.meteor.com`

Comment: "I've a self hosted meteor application" - which means that I'm not using Meteor free hosting.